# object oriented bind_pram undefined function

Tags: php

How do I solve this problem?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function bind_param() in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\functions.php on
>   line 15

```
<?php
define('STATUS_ACTIVE', 0);
define('STATUS_DELETE', 1);

function getCategoryArrConn($conn, $status) {
$result = array();
if(!$conn->connect_error) {
    $sqlstr = "SELECT cat, title, img, desc " .
            "FROM category WHERE status=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlstr);
    $stmt = bind_param("i", $status);     //error in the line of code
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($cat, $title, $img, $desc);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result[$cat] = ["cat" => $cat,
                         "title" => $title,
                         "img" => $img,
                         "desc" => $desc];
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
return $result;
}
?>
```

It's linked to another PHP file where the function goes:

```
$categoryArr = getCategoryArrConn($conn, STATUS_ACTIVE);
```

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param()`, e.g. RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php or http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php, depending on whichever library you're using.

Comment: ^ simply `F`abulous.

Comment: `desc` oh... now there's another tid bit that's going to fail on you. You're not checking for errors. :p

Comment: ^ missed that one @MarcB - Now there's a stick in the guy's front bike wheel.

Comment: Since they use `connect_error` I assume MySQLi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call bind_param like this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $status);
```

Also, as noted by the comments it would be wise to add error checks in your code when dealing with the DB and also change the name of the column `desc` because it's a MySQL reserved word.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Either rename your "desc" column to something else, or wrap it in ticks:

```
$sqlstr = "SELECT cat, title, img, `desc` " .
```

Comment: ^ That's only a partial find.

Comment: @AbraCadaver *"Yet"*, being the operative "word" ;-) I guess they'll get to that gauntlet eventually.

Comment: There we have it ;-) @AbraCadaver He's figured it out. I added my 2 cents in there after.

Comment: I would call that green ticky an "assist" ;-) sort of like hockey.